# Would itune/Appstore users will see App Review Information

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

I would like to add new version for my application in itune, but Apple asked me to fill **App Review Information** with info like name, email ,tel number.

I wonder if this details will be visible to users of itune/appstore, or it just for Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "App Review Information" is strictly for Apple. Users will never see that information. The data is there so Apple can contact you if there is a problem found while reviewing your app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. Typically I've seen an LLC or maybe a developers name, but as far as contact information goes, I have not seen that. Perhaps providing a way for users to contact the developer though would be handy to receive, and subsequently implement feedback.